# Choropleth maps in plotly with detailed borders

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to plot a world map, where the colors correspond to a specific variable. However, it does not show small states like "Andorra" or "Liechtenstein", even though they are in the data frame. I think the problem is, that the borders are not drawn with much detail. Is there a way draw the borders with more detail like with the packs, `maps`, and `mapdata` (`e. g wolrd_detailed <- map_data ("worldHires")`?
Here is the example from the plotly website. It does not show small states:

```
library(plotly)   
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_world_gdp_with_codes.csv")
fig <- plot_ly(df, type='choropleth', locations=df$CODE, z=df$GDP..BILLIONS., text=df$COUNTRY, colorscale="Blues")
fig
```